# Monitor WebRTC bit rate in Android application

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I am trying to develop a Video Calling application in Android using WebRTC. I need to show the live video upload bitrate to the other caller during the video call. 
is there any way to fetch the upload video bitrate and set different video quality by controlling the bandwidth during video call.

Comment: What you need to implement is "Simulcast" streaming. This can manually/automatically change the video quality based on the available bandwidth.

Comment: Ik know simulcast is used in the mediasoup sfu

Answer (score 1):

HardwareVideoEncoder.java
function, public VideoCodecStatus setRates(RateControlParameters rcParameters) {
can log bitrate.

Comment: Please provide some code style for your code in order to make clear and readable answer